# jp@gc - WebDriver Sampler in JMeter

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, jmeter

I just need to select a value from “smart search pick-list” (drop down list) from a web page using webdriver sampler in Jmeter. I already tried using one of it’s pick-list value’s xpath & id and it doesn’t work.

xpath value for "smart search pick-list" field is

```
.//*[@id='j_id0:frm:searchDiagnosisId']
```

xpath value for "smart search pick-list" field's one of the value is

```
.//*[@id='ui-id-21']
```

If I use sendKeys method, input value just appearing in the text box and not selecting values below. And also remaining script are not executed to fill remaining fields in the webpage. Can you give a solution to select a value from “smart search pick-list”.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

People mostly use [Select class](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html) in order to interact with the "dropdown lists", the relevant WebDriver Sampler code will look somehow like:

```
var select = new org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select(WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath(".//*[@id='j_id0:frm:searchDiagnosisId']")))
select.selectByValue("....")
```

See [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered) article for more WebDriver sampler tips and tricks